# Negative Lookahead in RegExp not working as expected

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to write two RegExp: A first one that matches Strings starting with a tag that is not <sub> or <sup>. And then a second one that matches Strings ending with a tag that is not </sub> or </sup>.

The String **<i>CH<sub>5</sub></i>** should match both RegExp.

The String **<sup>Something</sup>** should not match any of the two RegExp.

I thought that [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) might be worth a try, but somehow that doesn't work as expected.

For the 'starts with non-sub/sup-tag' I used the following: **^<(?!su[bp])>.+**

For the 'ends with non-sub/sup-tag' I used the following: **.+</(?!su[bp])>**

Both are not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patterns are not matching because the assertion `(?!su[bp])` is always true as the next thing the patterns are matching is `>`.

So the first one will match for example `<>a` and the second will match for example `a</>`

---

<sup>***** For the example, assuming the chars `<` and `>` can not occur before the closing `>`</sup>

If you want 2 patterns, in the first pattern you could first match till the closing `>` before matching the rest of the line.

```
^<(?!su[bp]\b)[^<>]+>.+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `<` Match literally
- `(?!su[bp]\b)` Negative lookahead, assert what is direct to the right is not sub or sup
- `[^<>]+>` Match 1+ times any char other than `<` and `>`
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzAO3b/1)

In the second pattern you could so the same, but you do have to match what is before the closing `>` as a lookahead is non consuming.

```
.+</(?!su[bp]\b)[^<>]+>$
```

- `.+` Match 1+ times any char
- `</` Match literally
- `(?!su[bp]\b>)` Negative lookahead, assert what is direct to the right is not sub or sup
- `[^<>]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `<` and `>`
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVRLYJ/1)

**Notes**

- Using `.+` is a very broad match and the dot will match any character.
- If you are processing structured data like html or xml I would advise you to look into a parser instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Both are working well. As always when using it in Java: one shouldn't forget to escape the backslashes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think of lookaheads with regard to position.

In `^<(?!su[bp])>.+`, you're telling the engine to match this sequence:

- The start of the line
- A `<`
- The position after `<` should not be followed by sub or sup
- A `>`
- One of more characters

The third condition is where you're thinking of it incorrectly.

The regex you want is:

```
^<(?!sub[bp]).+?>.+
```

So you're telling the engine to match as few characters as possible between `<` and `>` (given by `.+?`), but `<` should not be followed by sub or sup

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the RegExp also matches <sup>Something</sup>.